# Как разместить элемент внутри listview в центре строки?

Tags: java, android, listview

При создании списка и заполнении его словами, они автоматически выравниваются по левому краю. Можно ли как то сделать выравнивание по центру?

Описание listview:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/version"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/about_list" />
```

Заполнение его данными:

```
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.about_list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.element_of_about, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.about_choose));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Вид собственной разметки textview(element_of_about):

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Пробный текст"
style="@style/text_of_breed"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="17sp"/>
```

С такими настройками текст все равно слева получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В разметке `TextView` поменяйте `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` на `android:layout_width="match_parent"`